# Run NUnit automated tests after TFBuild completes

Tags: tfs, nunit

I'm possibly in over my head here, but I've been asked to set up a scheduled Team Foundation Build for our team's branch and then after the build completes for our automated tests to be executed using NUnit.

I've had a look at a few online tutorials on setting up the build definition in TFS, but I can't seem to figure out how to call NUnit after the build is successful. I was expecting to see or find some kind of "run this command line on success" option somewhere; the best I could find is "Pre/Post-test script path", but that's related to tests like `**\*test*.dll;**\*test*.appx` and I'm not sure what that is.

Just knowing what to Google for would be a help, as I am at a loss now.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Are you using XAML build or new task based build?

Comment: TFS 2013, I'm just creating a new build in Visual Studio - `Team Explorer > Builds > New Build Definition`

Answer (score 0):

**If you use XAML build:**

You can either install the [NUnit Test Adapter](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnitTestAdapter/) NuGet package in the unit test project. Or you can [check the assemblies into the Build Controller's Custom Assemblies Path](http://www.mytechfinds.com/articles/software-testing/6-test-automation/72-running-nunit-tests-from-team-foundation-server-2012-continuous-integration-build).

Useful article:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2013/06/11/part-3-unit-testing-with-traits-and-code-coverage-in-visual-studio-2012-using-the-tfs-build-and-the-new-nuget-adapter-approach/
- https://www.codit.eu/blog/2015/03/18/continuous-integration-with-javascript-nunit-on-tfsbuild-part-3-of-3-/

**If you use new task based build**:

You can add the NUnit Test Adapter NuGet package to your solution, and specify the path of NUnit Test Adapter NuGet package in the `Path to Custom Test Adapters` field in VSTest task. Check the screenshot below:

[image]

Useful article:

- http://bartwullems.blogspot.sg/2015/10/team-foundation-server-2015enable-nunit.html